# Filling blank space or embedding while a window is resizing (Qt)

Tags: qt, user-interface, window, qt5, qt-designer

[Video, which is showing defference between resizing in GTK and Qt](https://youtu.be/pqdCD4Akwhs)
How to make *"smart resizing"* using Qt Designer?

**UI files:**

- [Qt UI file](http://pastebin.com/zY6Wp4uY)
- [GTK Glade file](http://pastebin.com/f7MmPebc)

I prefer to use **Qt Designer** and **Python 3 (PyQt5)**

Comment: Set a layout on the main-window/central-widget.

Comment: @ekhumoro, Vertical Layout was on centralwidget...

Comment: Nope. The central-widget *contains* a child layout, but that is irrelevant. You need to set a layout directly on the central-widget itself, as I said before.

Comment: @ekhumoro, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added layout (Lay Out -> Lay Out Vertically). Thank @ekhumoro.